# MCTS: Monte Carlo Tree Search in Checkers

Tags: artificial-intelligence, montecarlo, game-ai

I implemented an AI playing checkers (also known as draughts) using the popular [Monte Carlo Tree Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search).

I was inspired by this resource http://www.bailopan.net/checkers/ that does the same.

Unfortunately my implementation and that implementation have an issue:
While the AIs play very well during early and middle stages of the game they do not handle end-game too well: **i found they end up just moving the last pieces around and not trying to win**.

I implemented the **simulation step** making random moves for both players for N turns in the future (ie: it does not simulate the game until the end but for a **significant** number of turns).

I gave to the AI a large amount of time for its considerations just to be sure that computational time was not the bottleneck.

I'm considering to tweak the simulation step with some domain-based heuristic but i don't know how to develop the evaluate function, if needed.

Under this circumstances, how do you think I can improve my AI to have a better late game?

Comment: Do you reward (as in reward function) winning the game over playing useless moves in a certain win situation?

Comment: @ziggystar Could you please add more detail?

I'll try to be more explicit:
Simulation step does two things
-it simulates nTurns in the future and returns a winner
-if no winner it makes a static evaluation of the board at the end of the simulation and return a winner
- if no winner even in this case the simulation returns NO winner.

Nodes update their scores with +1 if they are winning nodes, otherwise -1.

Comment: I meant that you should add some incentive to win the game fast. Either by changing the move generator, or by giving a small reward.